# Compute the summation of a given interval using multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

For my homework, I need to compute the squares of integers in the interval (0,N) (e.g. (0,50) in a way that the load is distributed equally among threads (e.g. 5 threads). I have been advised to use small chunks from the interval and assign it to the thread. For that, I am using a queue. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define QUEUE_SIZE 50
typedef struct {
    int q[QUEUE_SIZE];
    int first,last;
    int count;
} queue;

void init_queue(queue *q)
{
    q->first = 0;
    q->last = QUEUE_SIZE - 1;
    q->count = 0;
}

void enqueue(queue *q,int x)
{
    q->last = (q->last + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
    q->q[ q->last ] = x;
    q->count = q->count + 1;
}

int dequeue(queue *q)
{
    int x = q->q[ q->first ];
    q->first = (q->first + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
    q->count = q->count - 1;
    return x;
}

queue q; //declare the queue data structure

void* threadFunc(void* data)
{   
    int my_data = (int)data; /* data received by thread */

    int sum=0, tmp;

    while (q.count)
    {
        tmp = dequeue(&q);
        sum = sum + tmp*tmp;
        usleep(1);
    }
    printf("SUM = %d\n", sum);

    printf("Hello from new thread %u - I was created in iteration %d\n",pthread_self(), my_data);   
    pthread_exit(NULL); /* terminate the thread */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    init_queue(&q);
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        enqueue(&q, i);
    }

    pthread_t *tid = malloc(5 * sizeof(pthread_t) );

    int rc; //return value

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        rc = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, threadFunc, (void*)i);
        if(rc) /* could not create thread */
        {
            printf("\n ERROR: return code from pthread_create is %u \n", rc);
            return(-1);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

}
```

The output is not always correct. Most of the time it is correct, 40425, but sometimes, the value is bigger. Is it because of the threads are running in parallel and accessing the queue at the same time (the processor  on my laptop is is intel i7)? I would appreciate the feedback on my concerns.

Comment: Go back and review race conditions.

Comment: And yes, the `usleep` accomplishes nothing. With a chunk size of 50 it should be able to do the entire computation in one microsecond. I suspect that all it's doing is hiding your race condition. Also, that is definitely *not* how you should structure your code (even if it was thread safe).

Comment: Woudn't `usleep` let the scheduler  to re-shedule it after the specified time? Isn't this a nice resource sharing approach? @kulan, how you're saying it's in-efficeint?

Comment: @nmxprime Fair enough, I didn't fully understand usleep. I will edit my post. However, I still don't know why sometimes I get the wrong output.

Comment: The code fully ignores the fact that concurrent access to shared resouces (here: the queue) shall be synchronised. Read about mutexes and/or semaphores.

Comment: the usleep will be much longer, because there is a minimum timeslice for threads. It think (not sure) it will be at least 10 ms on windows.

Comment: @Adam thank you for the tip. I've reviewed race conditions, learned a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think contrary to what some of the other people here suggested, you don't need any synchronization primitives like semaphores or mutexes at all. Something like this:

Given some array like

```
int values[50];
```

I'd create a couple of threads (say: 5), each of which getting a pointer to a struct with the offset into the `values` array and a number of squares to compute, like

```
typedef struct ThreadArgs {
    int *values;
    size_t numSquares;
} ThreadArgs;
```

You can then start your threads, each of which being told to process 10 numbers:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    ThreadArgs *args = malloc( sizeof( ThreadArgs ) );
    args->values = values + 10 * i;
    args->numSquares = 10;
    pthread_create( ...., threadFunc, args );
}
```

Each thread then simply computes the squares it was assigned, like:

```
void *threadFunc( void *data )
{
    ThreadArgs *args = data;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < args->numSquares; ++i ) {
        args->values[i] = args->values[i] * args->values[i];
    }
    free( args );
}
```

At the end, you'd just use a [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) to wait for all threads to finish, after which you have your squares in the `values` array.

Comment: This is the correct approach for the work distribution, but you forget that there is a single `sum`. But don't fix your answer, this is *homework* after all.

Answer (score 1):

All your threads read from the same queue. This leads to a race condition. For instance, if the number 10 was read simultaneously by two threads, your result will be offset by 100. You should protect your queue with a mutex. Put the following print in deque function to know which numbers are repeated:

```
printf("Dequeing %d in thread %d\n", x, pthread_self());
```

Your code doesn't show where the results are accumulated to a single variable. You should protect that variable with a mutex as well.

Alternatively, you can pass the start number as the input parameter to each thread from the loop so that each thread can work on its set of numbers. First thread will work on 1-10, the second one on 11-20 and so on. In this approach, you have to use mutex only the part where the threads update the global sum variable at the end of their execution.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define what it means to be "distributed equally among threads." If you mean that each thread does the same amount of work as the other threads, then I would create a single queue, put all the numbers in the queue, and start all threads (which are the same code.) Each thread tries to get a value from the queue which must be protected by a mutex unless it is thread safe, calculates the partial answer from the value taken from the thread, and adds the result to the total which must also be protected by a mutex. If you mean that each thread will execute an equal amount of times as each of the other threads, then you need to make a priority queue and put all the numbers in the queue along with the thread number that should compute on it. Each thread then tries to get a value from the queue that matches its thread number. From the thread point of view, it should try to get a value from the queue, do the work, then try to get another value. If there are no more values to get, then the thread should exit. The main program does a join on all threads and the program exits when all threads have exited.

Comment: This would only be efficient if the single tasks are large enough. In this case (a simple multiply), all the locking is a adding more overhead than the actual calculations. Dividing the work in large chucks would be better here.

Comment: But the word "efficient" is not in the problem statement.